# keypress key event listener triggers the shift key input

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, onkeypress

i have this piece of javascript code

```
    keyPos = 0;
keySeq = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
keySeqUser = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39];

var logKeys = function(evt) {
  key = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which ? evt.which : evt.charCode;

  if (keyPos <= 9) {
    keySeqUser.push(key);
    keyPos++;
  } else {
    keySeqUser = [];
    keyPos=0;
  }
  if (keySeqUser.toString() == keySeq.toString()) {
    $(".page").hide();
    $(".lanes").fadeIn().animate({height: "600px"}, 2000);
    $(".pin").hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".pin").show().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    }, 2500);
    attemptKeyCombo();
  }
  console.log(keySeqUser.toString());
}

document.body.addEventListener("keypress", logKeys);
```

this webpage is hidden and in order to open it i should open it by pressing the same key combo which is stored within the variable `keySeq`, when i open the webpage and try to apply the same key combo [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65] which is in ASCII to text editor translates into `&&((%'%'BA`, i have tried to do that but the console on google chrome on windows 7 trigers the shift input and the sequence become screwed up.

when i press a key that ascii value of the key pressed is stored within the `keySeqUser` and when the value of that variable equals the value of the `keySeq` the webpage opens, i have no idea why the `keypress` event registers the shift key input

note: i am checking the value from the browser's console `console.log()`

Comment: well now it's not recording the shift input but it input the key code two times and i don't know why it duplicates the key input

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code. I [tested it](https://jsfiddle.net/pwfq2ej9/), I held shift B, then A. And it was a success.